# Difference between Flux.concat and Flux.concatWith

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am new to reactive streams and learning the combine two publishers (Flux to be specific) using the concat/concatWith methods.

Everything which i can do with concat method, the same can be achieved using the concatWith method. Here is the sample cases which i used:

```
        Mono<String> mono1 = Mono.just(" karan ");
        Mono<String> mono2 = Mono.just(" | verma ");
        Mono<String> mono3 = Mono.just(" | kv ");

        Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just(" {1} ","{2} ","{3} ","{4} " );
        Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just(" |A|"," |B| "," |C| ");

        // FLux emits item each 500ms
        Flux<String> intervalFlux1 = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                                        .zipWith(flux1, (i, string) -> string);

        // FLux emits item each 700ms       
        Flux<String> intervalFlux2 = Flux
                                .interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                                .zipWith(flux2, (i, string) -> string);



        System.out.println("**************Flux Concat***************");
        Flux.concat(mono1, mono2, mono3).subscribe(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
        Flux.concat(flux2, flux1).subscribe(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
        Flux.concat(intervalFlux2, flux1).subscribe(System.out::print);

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println();
        Flux.concat(intervalFlux2, intervalFlux1).subscribe(System.out::print);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");


        System.out.println("**************Flux Concat with***************");
        mono1.concatWith(mono2).concatWith(mono3).subscribe(System.out::print);
        System.out.println();
        flux1.concatWith(flux2).subscribe(System.out::print);

        System.out.println();
        intervalFlux1.concatWith(flux2).subscribe(System.out::print);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println();
        intervalFlux1.concatWith(intervalFlux2).subscribe(System.out::print);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
```

and here is the output for both the cases:

```
**************Flux Concat***************
 karan  | verma  | kv 
 |A| |B|  |C|  {1} {2} {3} {4} 
 |A| |B|  |C|  {1} {2} {3} {4} 
 |A| |B|  |C|  {1} {2} {3} {4} ----------------------------------------
**************Flux Concat with***************
 karan  | verma  | kv 
 {1} {2} {3} {4}  |A| |B|  |C| 
 {1} {2} {3} {4}  |A| |B|  |C| 
 {1} {2} {3} {4}  |A| |B|  |C| 
----------------------------------------
```

and the time complexity was also similar for both cases.

What is the difference between the two?
Is there any specific conditions, when concat or concatWith should be used?

Comment: They are equivalent. Some people prefer "always member functions" others prefer "static functions when taking two (or more) of same class"

Comment: @Caleth that should be an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Reactor Merge vs Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478420/spring-reactor-merge-vs-concat)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### They are equivalent

Java requires that all code be part of a class, so you can't just have `Flux concat(Flux, Flux)` as a free function, which *imo* would be the least confusing.

Some people prefer "always member functions" others prefer "static functions when taking two (or more) of same class".

A third alternative would be a constructor of the form `Flux::Flux(Flux, Flux)` (or `Flux::Flux(Flux[])`)