# Spring Reactor Merge vs Concat

Tags: java, spring, flux, reactor

I´m playing with Spring reactor, and I cannot see any differences between `concat` and `merge` operator

Here's my example

```
    @Test
    public void merge() {
        Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("hello").doOnNext(value -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just("reactive").doOnNext(value -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Flux<String> flux3 = Flux.just("world");
        Flux.merge(flux1, flux2, flux3)
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    @Test
    public void concat() {
        Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("hello").doOnNext(value -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just("reactive").doOnNext(value -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Flux<String> flux3 = Flux.just("world");
        Flux.concat(flux1, flux2, flux3)
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);    
}
```

Both behave exactly the same. Can someone explain the difference between the two operations?

Answer (score 19):

The essential difference between merge and concat is that in merge, both streams are live. In case of concat, first stream is terminated and then the other stream is concatenated to it.

[**Concat**](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-)
[image]

---

[**Merge**](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#merge-java.lang.Iterable-)
[image]

Comment: But then how it’s possible that the order of emission in the merge is always the same?

Comment: What is the sequence?

Comment: Flux 1, 2 and 3 all the time

Comment: And is there any time difference?

Comment: Nope, never, that’s the reason of my question

Answer (score 13):

The difference is already mentioned in the API docs that while **concat** first reads one flux completely and then appends the second flux to that, **merge** operator doesn't guarantee the sequence between the two flux.

In order to see the difference, modify your merge() code as below.

e.g. sample code below

```
//Flux with Delay
@Test
public void merge() {
    Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("Hello", "Vikram");

    flux1 = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(3000))
    .zipWith(flux1, (i, msg) -> msg);
    
    
    Flux<String> flux2 = Flux.just("reactive");
    flux2 = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
            .zipWith(flux2, (i, msg) -> msg);
    
    Flux<String> flux3 = Flux.just("world");
    Flux.merge(flux1, flux2, flux3)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(8000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you modify the Flux.interval duration, currently set as 3000 milliseconds you will see that the output with merge() keeps changing. But with concat(), the output will be always same.

Comment: Hi @Vikram Rawat, the output of your example is reactive,world,Hello,Vikram. Why is not shown first the word "world" if it doesn't have any sleep?

Comment: Hi @AleGallagher, good catch.. I have edited the code.. if you run it the output will be world, reactive, Hello, Vikram. The earlier code was calling a sleep in doOnNext, which was putting the subscriber to sleep rather than delaying the emission of "reactive" from flux 2. So, I changed the flux2 to now delay the emission of the data ("reactive"). Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Another noteworthy difference is that all variations of concat subscribe to the second stream **lazily**, only after the first stream has terminated.

Whereas all variations of merge subscribe to the publishers **eagerly** (all publishers are subscribed together)

Running the below code highlights this aspect:

```
//Lazy subscription of conact
Flux.concat(Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500)),
                Flux.just(10, 20, 30, 40).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);



//Eager subscription of the merge. Also, try mergeSequential.
Flux.merge(Flux.range(500, 3).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500)),
                Flux.range(-500, 3).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300)))
                .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1st example:  Flux<String> stringFlux= Flux.just("a","b").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(200));
        Flux<String> stringFlux1= Flux.just("c","d").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300));
        Flux<String> stringFlux2=Flux.merge(stringFlux,stringFlux1);
                stringFlux2.subscribe(System.out::println);
                Thread.sleep(4000);
output: a
        c
        b
        d
2nd example: Flux<String> stringFlux= Flux.just("a","b");
        Flux<String> stringFlux1= Flux.just("c","d");
        Flux<String> stringFlux2=Flux.merge(stringFlux,stringFlux1);
                stringFlux2.subscribe(System.out::println);
                Thread.sleep(4000);
output: a a c
        c b a
        b c d 
        d d b
conclusion: if you dont give delay to the elements then publishers are subscribed eagerly and output would be random as in 2nd example case.
If you specify delay to the elements then in which publisher you provide less amount of time will subscribed first and emit element and then other publisher emit elements as in 1st example.
It totally depends upon time for example output for below would be :
c,d,a,b because there is big diff between 2 seconds and 300 milliseconds. But in 1st example there is less diff between milliseconds so output would be in **interleaving fashion**.
3rd example :
Flux<String> stringFlux= Flux.just("a","b").delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
Flux<String> stringFlux1= Flux.just("c","d").delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300));
```